# Encrypt backup in 2008 R2

Tags: backup, encryption, ssrs-2008-r2

Is it possible to encrypt 2008 R2 backups like TDE for instance?

What I've read is encrypting the whole database and that way the backups will be encrypted. But can you have TDE encrypted backups alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Backup Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/backup-encryption?view=sql-server-ver15#:%7E:text=%20Backup%20Encryption%20%201%20Overview.%20Starting%20in,key%20that...%204%20See%20Also.%20%20More%20) was added in SQL Server 2014.

And SQL 2008 R2 is out of support.  So upgrade, and yes, otherwise you can use TDE, or write ordinary backups to an encrypted location (eg with BitLocker).

Comment: Thank you, I know it's out of support :( (not to my liking)